# Mart way of counting integral

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I have one question: Is there any easy way to count that integral:
$\int^{\infty}_0\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}x^2\cdot\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})\,dx$? I know this is equal $\frac{1}{2}$ by probability theory i.e. we know that $EX^2=1$, where $X$ has standard normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ but I am wondering if there is any simple way to count it directly?

Comment: Yes. You can use double integral -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#Computation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x=\sqrt{2m}$, then $dx=\frac{dm}{\sqrt{2m}}$ and the integral is$$\int^{\infty}_0x^2e^{-x^2/2}~dx=\sqrt2\int_0^\infty\sqrt m~e^{-m}dm=\sqrt2\Gamma(3/2)$$In general, to compute $\int_0^\infty x^re^{-x^2/2}dx$ for $r>-1$, begin by substituting $x/\sqrt2=m$, giving$$2^{(r-1)/2}\left[2\int_0^\infty m^re^{-m^2}dm\right]$$The expression inside the brackets is $\Gamma\left(\frac{r+1}2\right)$, so the result is $2^{(r-1)/2}\Gamma\left(\frac{r+1}2\right)$.

Comment: Of course! We can use Gamma distribution. Thank you.